# Need help in creating an appropriate model to predict semantic similarity between two sentences

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-modeling, word2vec

I am new to ML field and trying my hands on creating a model which will predict semantic similarity between two sentences.
I am using following approach:

1.Using word2vec model in gensim package vectorise each word present in the sentences in question

2.Calculate the average vector for all words in every sentence/document

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial

index2word_set = set(model.wv.index2word)

def avg_feature_vector(sentence, model, num_features, index2word_set):
    words = sentence.split()
    feature_vec = np.zeros((num_features, ), dtype='float32')
    n_words = 0
    for word in words:
        if word in index2word_set:
            n_words += 1
            feature_vec = np.add(feature_vec, model[word])
    if (n_words > 0):
        feature_vec = np.divide(feature_vec, n_words)
    return feature_vec
```

3.Next calculate cosine similarity between these two average vectors

```
s1_afv = avg_feature_vector('this is a sentence', model=model, 
num_features=300, index2word_set=index2word_set)
s2_afv = avg_feature_vector('this is also sentence', model=model, 
num_features=300, index2word_set=index2word_set)
sim = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(s1_afv, s2_afv)
print(sim)
```

Reference stackoverflow question:
[How to calculate the sentence similarity using word2vec model of gensim with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129943/how-to-calculate-the-sentence-similarity-using-word2vec-model-of-gensim-with-pyt)

Help needed for the following challenge:

As I want to create a model which would predict semantic similarity between two sentences, I am not quite sure about:

1.Which model would be best suited for this problem

2.Next more importantly how to train that model?

Should I create a matrix where each row will contain two sentences: 
sen1 and sen2 and I would vectorise them and calculate cosine similarity(as per the above mentioned approach)

Then for training data:

X_Train: avg vectors for sen1 and sen2 and their cosine similarity value

y_Train(prediction) : a set of binary values(1 or similar if cosine similarity > 0.7 and 0 otherwise)

I am quite confused whether my approach is correct and how to put a proper approach in the form of a working codebase.

Internet and materials available online are my only teachers to learn ML; thus requesting your guidance in help clearing my gap in understanding and help in coming up with a good working model for my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your general approach is reasonable. An average of the word-vectors in a sentence often works OK as a rough summary vector of the sentence. (There are many other possible techniques which might do better, but that's a good easy start.)

You can use someone else's pre-trained word-vectors, but if you have a good large training set of text from your domain, those word-vectors may work better. You should look for a tutorial on how to train your own word-vectors with `gensim`. For example, there'a a demo Jupyter notebook `word2vec.ipynb` included with it, in its `docs/notebooks` directory, which you can also view online at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/word2vec.ipynb

Your current `avg_feature_vector()` function has a number of problems. In particular:

- if you pass in the `model`, it already includes within it the fixed `index2word` list, and an already-determined number-of-dimensions – so no need to pass those in redundantly
- you're looping over all words in the model, rather than just the ones in your sentence, so not calculating just based on your sentence
- there are better, more pythonic ways to do the various array math operations you're attempting - including in the `numpy` library a simple `mean()` function that will spare you the adding/dividing of creating the average

You may want to fix those problems, as an exercise, but you could also use utility methods on the word-vectors `model` instead. In particular, look at `n_similarity()` - it specifically takes two sets-of-words, automatically averages each set, then reports the similarity-value (closer to 1.0 for more-similar, closer to -1.0 for least-similar) between the two sets. See:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors.n_similarity

So if you had two sentences (as strings) in `sent1` and `sent2`, and a set of word-vectors (either just-trained by you, or loaded from elsewhere) in `kv_model`, you could get the sentence's similarity via:

```
kv_model.n_similarity(sent1.split(), sent2.split())
```

(You might still get errors if any of the word-tokens aren't known by the model.)

Whether you actually create average vectors for different sentences and store them in some list/dict/dataframe/etc, or simply remember the pairwise-similarities somewhere, will depend on what you want to do next.

And, after you have the basics working on this simple measure of text-similarity, you could look into other techniques. For example, another way to compare two texts using word-vectors – but not via the simple average – is called "Word Mover's Distance". (It's quite a bit slower to calculate, though.)

Another technique for collapsing texts into a single vector, for the purposes of comparison, is available in `gensim` as `Doc2Vec` – it works a lot like `Word2Vec` but also creates vectors-per-longer-text, instead of just vectors-per-individual-word.

Answer (score 1):

First of all thank you for asking this question, I am dabbling with same problem, first and foremost it is not a simple problem to solve because it deals with a nuance of a language and how to make a machine understand human language.

Since the time this question was asked to this time there have been a lot of changes that has happened in the ML/AI world so I thought updating this answer might help someone.

The problem with your approach is getting the average of all words in a sentence and averaging it out to get a derived vector for your sentence, given the tool of that time it might be okay but you should have gone with something more sophisticated like `Doc2Vec` from gensim.

For todays time I feel there exist way more sophisticated and effective word embedding rather sentence embedding that you can use.

List of few of them have been very cleverly curated at [this](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers) github repo from HuggingFace.

There is also an amazing discussion which I would love to point out to people reading this:

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/876

People often try to use a combination of ElasticSearch BM25 + Embeddings, but practical accuracy is still lower.

I am still in search of a semantic search technique which can help me do a semantic search over my domain data.

The closes thing is `Transfer Learning` where you can use a pre-trained model and add your domain data over it to finetune that model.

You can have a look at the example:
https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/application_semantic_search.py

But this way also we are not able to consider ontology and various scenarios where the word-overlap should come into picture.