# Analytics tools for Rasa

Tags: analytics, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have been doing some research for analytics solutions for a chatbot I am currently building using the Rasa framework. I found some solutions such as chatbase and dashbot. The documents dont provide this information, but does Rasa provide analytics tools? If not, what other tools would you recommend? I am looking for an analytic tool that will allow me to see what questions are asked the most. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are currently no dedicated open source analytic tools for Rasa.
What I suggest to do is either using a [persistent tracker store](https://rasa.com/docs/core/tracker_stores/), e.g. Mongo, or connect an [event broker](https://rasa.com/docs/core/brokers/), e.g. RabbitMq, to Rasa Core and store the streamed events as you like.
You can then write queries on top of that, or visualize the data with tools like Prometheus and Grafana.

Comment: Thank you this helps me narrow down my solutions!

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using Botanalytics. They have support for both voice and text based interfaces.

Plus, friendly UX and fast flowing analytics results.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above you can dump your logs to mongoDb and then do the analytics on your own, the challenge here is that you have to label you correct classifications and the wrong ones (i.e TP, FP etc)

If you want to see frequent questions, what you can do is to try and cluster together all similar sentences (first in a naive manner):

Calculate for each sentence a sum of all the vectors of the words and then calculate the cosine distance between them, here is a good start:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092200/1340604

By the way AFAIK Rasa offers analytics tool as part of their Rasa core enterprise license