# Distance between two word2vec in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have various keywords and phrases.
For ex : Keywords - happy, sad, angry and phrase- happy to read, angry on him etc

I have these keywords and phrases in the form of word2vec .
I need to check the distance between these keyword and phrase in order to check which keyword matches to which phrase.

I am using function cosine_similarity(v1,v2) from sklearn.metrics.pairwise. This function is returning a vector. I want to have distance in a digit or number form. so that I can keep threshold to conclude that these 2 vectors are similar. How to do that? How to convert that result vector into digit value

Comment: use [euclidean distance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html) to get the distance between 2 words

Comment: You can take median of the result vector for deriving a single digit value.

Comment: @Samiie : median is giving very low value even if both are same

Comment: This link solved this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092200/645825 and gives distance between two vectors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the sentence similarity using word2vec model of gensim with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129943/how-to-calculate-the-sentence-similarity-using-word2vec-model-of-gensim-with-pyt)