# Text classification with word2vec stack overflow tag predictor

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, text-classification

I am working stack overflow tag predictor.

I have a dataframe df which contains a feature 'post' and label 'Tags' which can be multi lable.

My df is :

```
Tags    post

0   [php]   check upload file image without mime type woul...

1   [firefox]   prevent firefox close press ctrl-w favorite ed...

2   [r] r error invalid type list variable import matl...
3   [c#]    replace special character url probably simple ...

4   [php, api]  modify whois contact detail function modify mc...

... ... ...
179995  [delphi]    intraweb isapi module throw unrecognized comma...

179996  [c] opencv argc argv confusion check opencv tutori...

179997  [android]   list data sdcard want display file name reside...

179998  [java, email]   add sort extension imap server mail server sup...

179999  [linux, php]    create carddav ldap server share host via php ...
```

So I want to use word2vec for classification and predict the tags.

I want to use all machine learning classifier like SVM,  random forest etc.

I also want classification report of tags.

So please help me.

Comment: Hi, I know you're new on this site and wanted to share some info that will help you. Your question is hard for someone to answer without more info, so please check https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/25240494 for information on how to ask a good question. While you're there, it would help to peruse more of the help documentation to make your use of this site more worthwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

word2vec is not a classifier it word to vector converter, my suggestion steps
1) Preprocess the text(like stopwords and normalization)
2) convert the words to vector using TF-IDF or word2vec
3) Then apply ml models (for multi classification you can use SVM, Naive Bayes and logistic regression)
4)validate the results

Comment: I completed it by TF-IDF . By I don't know how to do it with word2vec..Please can give me a Code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129943/how-to-calculate-the-sentence-similarity-using-word2vec-model-of-gensim-with-python..

Comment: go through the about stack you eill get idea.. you have to import using genism and use