# How to find similar sentence from a corpus on word2vec?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, sentence-similarity

I have implemented word2vec on my corpus using the TensorFlow tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word2vec#next_steps
Now I'm want to give a sentence as input and want to find a similar sentence in the corpus.

Any leads on how I can perform this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the sentence similarity using word2vec model of gensim with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129943/how-to-calculate-the-sentence-similarity-using-word2vec-model-of-gensim-with-pyt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple word2vec model is not capable of such task, as it only relates word semantics to each other, not the semantics of whole sentences. Inherently, such a model has no generative function, it only serves as a look-up table.

Word2vec models map word strings to vectors in the embedding space. To find similar words for a given sample word, one can simply go through all vectors in the vocabulary and find the ones that are closest (in terms of the 2-norm) from the sample word vector. For further information you could go [here](https://wiki.pathmind.com/word2vec) or [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-word2vec-embedding-in-practice-3e9b8985953).

However, this does not work for sentences as it would require a whole vocabulary of sentences of which to pick similar ones - which is not feasible.

Edit: This seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129943/how-to-calculate-the-sentence-similarity-using-word2vec-model-of-gensim-with-pyt?rq=1) question.